# Import past log files into Sentry

Tags: logging, log-files

We're exploring sentry.io

Is it possible to import historical logs into Sentry?

We're also looking at Prometheus and Grafana, and it looks like general SQL queries work for them, but it seems to me that I'd want to review error logs in the same place as new error logs are analyzed.

Answer (score 1):

I get the idea that a key concept of the product is that events get sent directly by the applications to Sentry, rather than relying on an intermediate step of first logging to a local (error) file.

AFAIK Therefor the product simply does not have any native support for "tailing" log files, log shipping and subsequently also not for generic importing of historical log files.

This https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/migration/ suggests:

> *"One thing to note is we won't be able to transfer over historical event data, but new incoming events will ..."*

---

Note: You *can* use the [sentry cli](https://docs.sentry.io/product/cli/send-event/)  to send perviously captured JSON events.

[Here:](https://clarkdave.net/2014/01/tracking-errors-with-logstash-and-sentry/) somebody uses logstash with a custom sentry/raven plugin for log shipping to Sentry, which may also be an approach to send your historic log files to Sentry.

Unfortunately most log files are line based and converting existing line based log files with multiline stack traces to (JSON) events is a big PITA. It can be done, we currently do log shipping  for numerous applications (in a different setting) with with the filebeat [multiline parser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html) rather than [the logstash multi-line codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-multiline.html)